# Google Calendar via Calendar.app—is a usable experience possible?

Tags: macos, ios, google-calendar

My company uses Google Workspace (aka G Suite, aka Google Apps for Business.) I use a Mac and iOS devices, and I would like to use the native calendar apps on those platforms to interface with Google Calendar. Is it even possible to get a reasonable experience doing this?

I want:

1. To receive one (1, singular, uno) macOS notification centre notification for each new calendar item.
2. To be able to respond to the request from the native notification UI (by selecting Decline/Maybe/Accept) and have that status immediately visible both locally in macOS Calendar and by other people on the web.
3. Alternatively, to have new calendar items appear in the macOS Calendar sidebar *once* (1, singular, uno) each, where I can respond and again have that status immediately reflected in Calendar's UI, and not change unless I change it.
4. To receive one (1, singular, uno, you get it...) notification for each upcoming meeting, ten minutes (or whatever) before the start time of said meeting.
5. To see items from the shared calendars in my company's Google Workspace *once each* in macOS Calendar, no duplicates. (Or ing *triplicates*, like I'm seeing right now.)
6. To have remote changes visible in macOS Calendar promptly (within 5 minutes, but preferably immediately.)
7. To be able to *create* items in our company shared calendars.

Currently it's an utter mess of duplicate items, duplicate appointments, a billion and one notifications for every appointment and everything has a random status no matter how many times and in how many places I click "Accept". Has anyone got this working in an acceptable fashion?

Comment: Via a private slack of former colleagues I trust to know about these kinds of things (paraphrased), "Give up, it'll never work properly, nobody at Apple or Google cares to make it work. Pay for Busycal or Fantastical instead."

Comment: Alternatively, apparently there once was a 3rd party service that stood in between Google Calendar and translated whatever garbage GCal output into proper CalDav—does anyone know of anything like that?